# FTP Server on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

I setup a ftp server on windows 2008  r2. it is dependent on IIS v7

I can log in remotely anonynomously which is the goal. However I cannot upload nor browse the directories like upload which is in the physical directory

I used this as a guide http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/321/configure-ftp-with-iis-70-manager-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

Did you double check both authentication methods and NTFS security settings in the related directory? Did you enable directory browsing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect locally on the server itself (ftp 127.0.0.1). It could be a firewall issue.